# How can the well-known Tintin become タンタン in Japanese?

Tags: katakana, loanwords

How can the well-known Tintin become タンタン rather than ティンティン in Japanese? Is it because ティンティン sounds like ちんちん?

[image]

Comment: Think: How would one pronounce 'Tintin' in French?

Comment: Lupin, Chopin, lingerie...

Comment: @brokenheadphones, thank you for that horrible mental image.  :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The タンタン rendering has a lot to do with the source French pronunciation, [[tɛ̃tɛ̃]].  The [[ɛ]] vowel in the [International Phonetic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) is the [open-mid front unrounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_front_unrounded_vowel), halfway between [[a]] and [[e]].  The tilde ~ on top indicates nasalization, like a half-pronounced [[n]] after a vowel.  To a Japanese ear (and, heck, even to my American English ear), [[tɛ̃tɛ̃]] sounds not too far from タンタン.

Avoiding the pronunciation [ちんちん]{chin chin} (slang for *"penis"*) is a nice side bonus.